# Checking if any contact in contact app has been changes (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, contacts, cncontact

Right now I build an app that provide sync contacts. For that, every time the app comeback to foreground, I check all contacts(CNContact) and compare to my contact in app's core data and detect if any contact that different and merge the data. It works okay but it takes a lot of memory.

Is that any way to detect if any contact in contact app has changed without comparing all contact?

Comment: Did you check the `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification`? It is telling you that something changed in your contact store but not exactly which contact. But you could save some compare operations.